# Can JavaScript .replace function with two search value?

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is my `replace()` function

```
SomeString.replace(/\[check\]/, "<input type='checkbox'>");
```

My question is: can I have two search value in replace function?

For example: if match `/\[check\]/`, replace to `<input type='checkbox'>`, and if match `\[check111\]`, replace to `<input type='radio'>`.

Can I write both two search value into one `.replace()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES.**

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) with callback function. And inside the callback, use ternary operator, or `if...else` statement to check what is matched and what should be replacement.

```
someString.replace(/\[check(?:111)?\]/g, function($0) {
    return "<input type='" + ($0 === '[check]' ? 'checkbox' : 'radio') + "'>";
    // $0 here is the complete string match
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var someString = 'Hello [check], did you say [check111]?';

var result = someString.replace(/\[check(?:111)?\]/g, function ($0) {
    return "<input type='" + ($0 === '[check]' ? 'checkbox' : 'radio') + "'>";
});

console.log(result);
document.body.innerHTML = result; // FOR DEMO ONLY
```

**RegEx Explanation:**

1. `\[check`: Match `[check`
2. `(?:111)?`: Match 111 zero or once and don't capture it. Thus `111` is optional here.
3. `\]`: Match `]` literal